# Z-index problem

Tags: html, css

I have a z-index problem here: http://ratingscorner.com/product_rating.php?alias=Peoples-Education-Society-Institute-of-Technology-%28PESIT%29-100-feet-Ring-Road-Bangalore&product=Colleges

The first level menus go behind the content area. I tried to give the header a higher z-index and it helped, but in IE the slideshow still doesn't get displayed. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE and Firefox render Div z-index in a diferent way . Give a z-index value to all divs.
So both browsers render the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `float:...` or `position:...` for z-index to work properly.

Something that made my head ache a lot of times already, till I figured it out...